# XML Parsing error: "extra content at the bottom of the document"

Tags: xml, parsing

Can anybody help me see why I'm getting the following error? : XML parsing error at line 10: extra content at the bottom of the document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item_templates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <item_template id="100000363" name="??? ??" level="30" mask="7256" weapon_type="SWORD_1H" max_stack_count="1" item_type="ABYSS" category="SWORD" quality="RARE" price="57600" race="PC_ALL" no_enchant="false" max_enchant="10" bonus_apply="EQUIP" option_slot_bonus="4" restrict="30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30" desc="1433409" attack_gap="0" attack_type="PHYSICAL"slot="3" equipment_type="WEAPON" m_slots="4">
        <modifiers>
            <add name="PVP_ATTACK_RATIO" value="24" bonus="true" />
        </modifiers>
        <weapon_stats min_damage="88" max_damage="108" attack_speed="1400" physical_critical="50" physical_accuracy="408" parry="472" magical_accuracy="107" attack_range="1500" hit_count="2" />
        <acquisition type="AP" ap="4900" />
    </item_template>
    <item_template id="100000364" name="??? ??" level="30" mask="7256" weapon_type="SWORD_1H" max_stack_count="1" item_type="ABYSS" category="SWORD" quality="RARE" price="57600" race="PC_ALL" no_enchant="false" max_enchant="10" bonus_apply="EQUIP" option_slot_bonus="4" restrict="30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30" desc="1433409" attack_gap="0" attack_type="PHYSICAL"slot="3" equipment_type="WEAPON" m_slots="4">
        <modifiers>
            <add name="PVP_ATTACK_RATIO" value="30" bonus="true" />
        </modifiers>
        <weapon_stats min_damage="108" max_damage="134" attack_speed="1400" physical_critical="50" physical_accuracy="540" parry="560" magical_accuracy="158" attack_range="1500" hit_count="2" />
        <acquisition type="AP" ap="11100" />
    </item_template>
</item_templates>
```

Comment: Open your xml content in application like Notepad++ even that will help

Comment: Or use any XML editor to check for errors.

Comment: Yeah, would be nice to figure out which extra content. and the error i've posted is what i get when i run the xml document in notepad++ with xml plugin.

Comment: looks like encoding error. are these names really question marks?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem:
use `attack_type="PHYSICAL" slot="3"` instead of `attack_type="PHYSICAL"slot="3"`
you just missed a space.

Comment: @user3254752 found the problem!

Comment: still getting the same error (not sure what's the difference between attack_type="PHYSICAL" slot="3" and attack_type="PHYSICAL" slot="3" tho)

Comment: did you change both lines that contain `attack_type="PHYSICAL" slot="3" `? I parsed it with space and it didn't give me any error any more.

Comment: also change the xml file encoding with notepad++ to utf-8 without BOM.

Comment: @user3254752 did my solution solved it? if not, what was the problem?

Comment: I'm getting this now: Error at [line ... column ... ] : null yet when i went to check out the error, there was nothing.